# How do I declare and call a function and array in Visual FoxPro 9.0

Tags: arrays, function, object, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to write a basic function that takes the values of 5 textboxes. I want to double the value of the first 2 Boxes to replace their former values with them and save the other 3 inside of an array. Then I want a for-loop to take the values inside of the array and get their sum in a new variable, which I want to display in a seperate TextBox.

Sorry for asking such an odd question but at the job I've just started it's tradition for apprentices to solves a bunch of these problems in FoxPro.

Comment: Can you post example of code you have attempted to show some fundamental level of your understanding of the language and coding constructs?  Then we can offer more help.  Also... are you passing the actual textbox controls as the parameter (thus the object) vs the actual value of the control (via yourTextbox.Value) field?

Answer (score 1):

You could paste the following code into a new PRG, e.g. by typing `Modify Command` into the Command Window, and then paste it there.

```
LOCAL oForm as Form
oForm = CREATEOBJECT("TestForm")
oForm.Show(1)
RETURN


DEFINE CLASS TestForm as Form
    AutoCenter = .T.

    ADD OBJECT TextBox1 as TextBox WITH Left = 20, Top = 20, Value = 1
    ADD OBJECT TextBox2 as TextBox WITH Left = 20, Top = 50, Value = 2
    ADD OBJECT TextBox3 as TextBox WITH Left = 20, Top = 80, Value = 3
    ADD OBJECT TextBox4 as TextBox WITH Left = 20, Top = 110, Value = 4
    ADD OBJECT TextBox5 as TextBox WITH Left = 20, Top = 140, Value = 5

    ADD OBJECT theOtherTextBox as TextBox WITH Left = 200, Top = 20
    ADD OBJECT cmdTest as CommandButton WITH Left = 200, Top = 80

    PROCEDURE cmdTest.Click
        Thisform.TextBox1.Value = Thisform.TextBox1.Value * 2
        Thisform.TextBox2.Value = Thisform.TextBox2.Value * 2

        LOCAL ARRAY laTest[3]
        STORE Thisform.TextBox3.Value TO laTest[1]
        STORE Thisform.TextBox4.Value TO laTest[2]
        STORE Thisform.TextBox5.Value TO laTest[3]

        LOCAL lnSum, lnValue
        lnSum = 0
        FOR lnValue = 1 TO ALEN(laTest)
            lnSum = m.lnSum + laTest[m.lnValue]
        ENDFOR && or alternatively
        lnSum = 0
        FOR EACH lnValue IN laTest
            lnSum = m.lnSum + m.lnValue
        ENDFOR
        Thisform.theOtherTextBox.Value = m.lnSum
    ENDPROC
ENDDEFINE
```

FWIW, the code-as-text presentation is just for the browser demo - in a real VFP project, you'd probably rather design "visual" things in the visual Form or Class designers, good luck John Doe